# Why doesn't this change my redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an array of array of objects in my state.
What I want to do is find the question with the correct id, then find the answer with the correct id to change it's value and update it to the state.

Here is what I got:

```
function updateObject(oldObject, newValues) {
  return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);
}

function updateItemInArray(array, questionId,answerId, updateItemCallback) {
  const getQuestion = array.map(item => {
    if(item.id !== questionId) {
      return item;
    }
  })
  const updatedItem = getQuestion[0].answers.map(answer => {
    if(answer.id !== answerId) {
      return answer;
    }
​
    const updatedItem = updateItemCallback(answer);
    return updatedItem;

  });
​
  return updatedItems;
}



export function answerUpdate(state = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ANSWER_UPDATE_FETCH_SUCCESS': {
      const newAnswer = updateItemInArray(state.project, action.questionId, action.answerId, answer => {
        return updateObject(answer, {value : action.newValue});
      });
    }
  }
}
```

the object I'm looking through is kinda obvious but it looks something like this

```
project = [
  question = {
    id:"some Id",
    answers:  [
    {
      id:"another id",
      value="someValue"
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

and some other properties but it is unrelevant for this question.
Thankful for every answer!

Comment: It's in a redux reducer, so the value i return in the function answerUpdate gets into my state

Comment: Yep, sorry, didn't see at first you were using redux. I guess this is because of the nested levels of array: when you use `setState` or redux, it only detects the "first level" of modification. If you modify something inside the state, it is not aware of it. You must clone the top object to pass a new one, so that it can be detected and trigger a refresh!

Comment: I don't know if i understand what you mean, how would that work practically?

Comment: Isn't that what i do here? : return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);

Comment: I meant the array! Sorry for the inaccuracy. When you create a new object, I think it compares it with the current state. Ok it's not the same instance, but to prevent refresh, it will tests children properties. It sees the same array, so it stops here and does not see that the content of the array changed. I'm gonna take a deeper look at it, but i can feel this is something like that I think!

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right, hmm

Answer (score 0):

You need to update data in map itself instead of creating variable, map function returns new array with updated value and you are updating 0th index of array which won't be one you're looking for.

```
function updateItemInArray(array, questionId,answerId, newValue) {
  return array.map(item => {
      if(item.id !== questionId) {
        return item;
      } else {
        item.answers.map(answer => {
          if(answer.id !== answerId) {
            return answer;
          } else {
            updateObject(answer, { value : newValue})
          }
        });
      }
    });
}

export function answerUpdate(state = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ANSWER_UPDATE_FETCH_SUCCESS': {
      return updateItemInArray(state, action.questionId, action.answerId, action.newValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But don't i need to return something in the switch in the reducer function?

Comment: Also @eramit2010 how do i after this reducer, get this into the state? Does it get into the state right after this reducer or do i need to recieve the value somewhere?

Comment: my bad. we need to return function itself.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Okey but it still doesn't change my state, do I need to recieve it somewhere? Right now i only have an action calling this reducer

Comment: have you created combine reducer?

Comment: Yeah but i haven't included that reducer, should i do it? How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174777/discussion-between-eramit2010-and-charlie).

Comment: I have this combined reducer, const allReducers = combineReducers({
    
    answerSelected: ChosenAnswer,
    allAnswers: AllAnswersChosen,
    tabClicked: TabClicked,
    headerOpen: ArrowClicked,
    project,
    projectHasErrored,
    projectIsLoading,
    projectId,
    qpId,
    categories,
    categoriesHasErrored,
    categoriesIsLoading,
});

export default allReducers;